# The Server could not complete you request

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

So Sharepoint Designer will no longer connect to any Of the Sites or subsites. I get the error message "The server could not complete your request. For more specific information click the details button" But when I click the details button there is no information there.

I believe that a windows update may have caused this but I have uninstalled several updates and still no luck.

Comment: A Fiddler trace taken while Designer is attempting to connect to the site would probably show what is really going on.

Comment: I'm also facing the exact issue.. Checked AAM ,
tried to access through IP,
Checked IIS Authentication still no luck.

Comment: And you can use [Sharepoint Log Viewer](http://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com) to view log in realtime. You can set logging level for the site collection in SP Central Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling ***Anonymous Authentication*** for your ***SharePoint Web Application*** & ***SharePoint Web Services*** in IIS Manager will resolve the issue.

Microsoft Support has further explanation on  the issue and can be found [here](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2758431).

Thanks to this [blog post.](http://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/fix-sharepoint-designer-2013-the-server-could-not-complete-your-request-for-more-specific-information-click-the-details-below/)

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to recycle the IIS application web

2) If doesn't work try IIS reset

It would definately work either of the ways.